# How to use termcolor to color text inside pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Here's what i have so far

```
# importing pandas as pd 
import pandas as pd 

from termcolor import colored
red = colored('red','red')
green = colored('green','green')
# Creating the DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Color1':[green], 
                    'Color2':[red] }) 
  
# Print the dataframe 
print (df)
```

This seems to work but the problem is the text that is colored is not aligned with the column on top and looks something like this (it's supposed to be colored)

```
           Color1        Color2
0  green  red
```

I'm supposed to write colored text using termcolor inside a table like format which is why I thought pandas dataframe would be an easy choice or should I use something else other than dataframe?